# XSLT to copy element without default/old namespace

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm converting from one XML document to another XML document by using XSLT. Both the input and output document types are in different default namespaces. I used to transform first and then filter with JAXB against the output schema. 
My requirement is: If publisher/catalogue/cd11/year is available/exist in the input xml then a new element with value need to created as publisher/catalogue/cd22 = 'New Release' in the out put xml. (fyi. publisher/catalogue/cd22 is exist in output schema)

Problem: When I transform using the below mentioned XSLT, the new node with output name space is getting created but the parent node is added with the input xml namespace / path-default-namespace (http://www.altova.com) , I'm not sure why this is being added but, i'm sure JAXB is filtering this to the desired output

can anyone help on this?

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.altova.com">
    <publisher>
        <Name id="d123">
            <Location>Chicago</Location>
        </Name>
        <catalogue id="d1" >
            <cd11 id="d2">
                <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
                <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
                <year>1985</year>
            </cd11>
        </catalogue>
        <catalogue id="d3" >
            <cd11 id="d4">
                <title>Jurassic World</title>
                <artist>Chris Pratt</artist>
            </cd11>
        </catalogue>    
    </publisher>
</root>
```

XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.altova.com" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com" >

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="catalogue[string(cd11/year)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       <xsl:element name="cd22" >
        <xsl:value-of select="'New Release'" />
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After Transform

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.com/">
    <publisher>
        <Name id="d123">
            <Location>Chicago</Location>
        </Name>
        <catalogue xmlns="http://www.altova.com" id="d1" >
            <cd11 xmlns="http://example.com/" id="d2">
                <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
                <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
                <year>1985</year>
            </cd11>
            <cd22 xmlns="http://example.com/">New Release</cd22>
        </catalogue>
        <catalogue id="d3" >
            <cd11 id="d4">
                <title>Jurassic World</title>
                <artist>Chris Pratt</artist>
            </cd11>
        </catalogue>    
    </publisher>
</root>
```

wrong output: After Filter with JAXB against the output schema which has namespace as xmlns="http://example.com/">

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.com/">
    <publisher>
        <Name id="d123">
            <Location>Chicago</Location>
        </Name>
        <catalogue id="d3" >
            <cd11 id="d4">
                <title>Jurassic World</title>
                <artist>Chris Pratt</artist>
            </cd11>
        </catalogue>    
    </publisher>
</root>
```

Desired Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.com/">
    <publisher>
        <Name id="d123">
            <Location>Chicago</Location>
        </Name>
        <catalogue id="d1" >
            <cd11 id="d2">
                <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
                <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
                <year>1985</year>
            </cd11>
            <cd22>New Release</cd22>
        </catalogue>
        <catalogue id="d3" >
            <cd11 id="d4">
                <title>Jurassic World</title>
                <artist>Chris Pratt</artist>
            </cd11>
        </catalogue>    
    </publisher>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNewNS" select="'http://example.com/'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vOldNS" select="namespace-uri(/*)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*"><xsl:copy/></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() eq $vOldNS]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$pNewNS}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template priority="3" match="*[@id eq 'd1']/*[*[name() = 'year']]">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <xsl:element name="cd22" namespace="{$pNewNS}">New Release</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.altova.com">
    <publisher>
        <Name id="d123">
            <Location>Chicago</Location>
        </Name>
        <catalogue id="d1" >
            <cd11 id="d2">
                <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
                <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
                <year>1985</year>
            </cd11>
        </catalogue>
        <catalogue id="d3" >
            <cd11 id="d4">
                <title>Jurassic World</title>
                <artist>Chris Pratt</artist>
            </cd11>
        </catalogue>    
    </publisher>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.com/">
   <publisher>
      <Name id="d123">
         <Location>Chicago</Location>
      </Name>
      <catalogue id="d1">
         <cd11 id="d2">
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <year>1985</year>
         </cd11>
         <cd22>New Release</cd22>
      </catalogue>
      <catalogue id="d3">
         <cd11 id="d4">
            <title>Jurassic World</title>
            <artist>Chris Pratt</artist>
         </cd11>
      </catalogue>
   </publisher>
</root>
```

---

**Explanation**:

1. Read and learn about the [**<xsl:element>**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-element) instruction.
2. Read and learn about the [**namespace-uri()**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-namespace-uri) function.
3. Read and learn about the [**<xsl:next-match>**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-next-match) instruction. Very few people are aware of this instruction and of the fact how powerful and useful it can be.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But have you undergone my conditions to be applied?  If publisher/catalogue/cd11/year is available/exist in the input xml then a new element with value need to created as publisher/catalogue/cd22 = 'New Release' in the out put xml

Comment: @GJ_15, I edited the solution and it now addresses your exact requirement.

Comment: @ Dimitre, Yes that works for me. And I modified the XSLT a little, by matching the Node name instead of the attribute. Thank you so much. It helped me a lot.